# Problemas con CSS GRID - No puedo fijar un tamaño

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un problema, tengo un panel-izq (izquierdo) y un panel-der (derecho), donde el izquierdo contiene un absoluto para agregar tareas y otro para buscar tareas, este cambia con un boton flecha abajo que hace un slide. Ahora, el problema esta en el panel derecho donde tengo un titulo arriba (ocupando toda la fila 1 a excepcion de la columna 1 que esa columna la ocupa todo el panel izquierdo). El resto de filas/columnas lo ocupa el panel derecho, siendo la fila 2-3 y la columna 2-3; el problema se encuentra en el tamaño del contenedor que ocupa estas dimensiones, ya que dentro contiene otro div que se llama .listado-tareas, cuando yo agrego tareas o mejor dicho elementos que son "li" que contienen un input checkbox, un titulo span y un boton; yo quiero que cuando llegue a un punto aparezca el overflow: auto, es decir, un scroll para que siga y siga poniendo elementos y el scroll se haga mas grande.

**Ahora, cuando mi contenedor**  ocupa una cierta cantidad de elementos no aparece el scroll, si no que el contenedor listado-tareas se hace cada vez mas grande llevandose consigo todo el panel izquierdo y derecho, es decir, comienzan a tomar mas altura tambien. Todo el panel izquierdo y todo el panel derecho que contiene este contenedor listado-tareas comienzan a crecer en proporcion a este contenedor. No se como evitar esto y que se genere el scroll. Ya probe usar max-height, height: 100% y height: auto en el contenedor panel-der o en listado-tareas pero sigue pasando lo mismo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To-do app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@24,400,0,0" />
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="contenedor">

        <div class="titulo"> <h1> Listado de tareas </h1> </div>

        <div class="panel-izq">
            <div id="panel-izq-item" class="active">
                <h1>Agregar tarea</h1>
                <input type="text" id="add-ingresar-titulo" class="ingresar-titulo" placeholder="Ingresar titulo tarea">
                <button id="agregar-titulo" class="agregar-titulo">Agregar</button>
            </div>
            
            <div id="panel-izq-item">
                <h1>Buscar tarea</h1>
                <input type="text" id="search-ingresar-titulo" class="ingresar-titulo" placeholder="Ingresar titulo tarea">
                <button id="buscar-titulo" class="buscar-titulo">Buscar</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="boton-izq" class="boton-izq"> <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> expand_more </span> </div>        

        <div class="panel-der">
            <div class="listado-tareas">
                <ul id="lista-item-tarea">
                    <!-- <li>
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <span>titulo tarea</span>
                        <button>Eliminar</button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <span>titulo tarea</span>
                        <button>Eliminar</button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <span>titulo tarea</span>
                        <button>Eliminar</button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <span>titulo tarea</span>
                        <button>Eliminar</button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <span>titulo tarea</span>
                        <button>Eliminar</button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <span>titulo tarea</span>
                        <button>Eliminar</button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <span>titulo tarea</span>
                        <button>Eliminar</button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <span>titulo tarea</span>
                        <button>Eliminar</button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <span>titulo tarea</span>
                        <button>Eliminar</button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <span>titulo tarea</span>
                        <button>Eliminar</button>
                    </li> -->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="agregarTarea.js"></script>
    <script src="cambiarTarjeta.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin-top: 80px;
    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
}

.contenedor {
    display: grid;
    width: 65%;
    margin: 55px auto;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: 50px auto 50px;
    place-content: center;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.contenedor > div {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 22px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.contenedor .panel-izq {
    background-color: bisque;
    grid-row: 1/3;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 500px;
}

.contenedor .panel-izq > div {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.contenedor .panel-izq .active {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 10;
}

/* ----- MANEJO DEL PANEL IZQUIERDO - INTERFAZ */

.contenedor .panel-izq div h1 {
    color: rgb(19, 19, 19);
    font-size: 27px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}

.contenedor .panel-izq div .ingresar-titulo {
    padding: 12px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
}

.contenedor .panel-izq div .agregar-tarea, .agregar-titulo, .buscar-titulo {
    background-color: rgb(238, 181, 75);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    padding: 12px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.contenedor .panel-izq div .agregar-tarea:hover, .agregar-titulo:hover, .buscar-titulo:hover {
    background-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .5s;
}

.contenedor .boton-izq {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 3;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.contenedor .boton-izq:hover {
    background-color: rgb(254, 209, 154);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .5s;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.contenedor .titulo {
    background-color: #12203E;
    color: white;
    grid-column: 2/-1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.contenedor .panel-der {
    min-height: 500px; /*Si quiero manejar mis columnas, debo establecer un maximo de ancho y largo segun sea el caso*/
    grid-column: 2/-1;
    grid-row: 2/4;
}

/* ----- MANEJO DEL PANEL DERECHA - TAREAS */

.contenedor .panel-der .listado-tareas {
    background-color: rgb(234, 234, 234);
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.contenedor .panel-der .listado-tareas ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 15px;
}

.contenedor .panel-der .listado-tareas ul > li {
    background-color: rgb(251, 198, 133);
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.contenedor .panel-der .listado-tareas ul li  input, button {
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.contenedor .panel-der .listado-tareas ul li button {
    background-color: rgb(255, 166, 0);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.completed {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------- */
```

Miren, por ejemplo, supongamos yo tengo este "main" mis dudas son:

1.- Digamos ese main es solo un titulo, pero si pongo un titulo aun tiene todo ese tamaño, como puedo yo hacer que por ejemplo solo sea de 100px sin afectar a todos los elementos y el responsive.

2.- Volvamos a tomar de ejemplo el main, supongamos hay un div mas dentro del main, que llamaremos "contenedor-listado", y en este agrego muchos items con `<lu> <li>`. Ahora el tema esta en que ese al llegar al maximo de ese cuadro como se ve, deberia sacar un scroll, asi si hay muchos elementos solo se mueven con un scroll en ese contenedor-listado; pero en mi caso no pasa, solo comienza a crecer el contenedor-listado y tambien el main, si bien podria desbordar, pero el main tiene un min-height de 500px que evita que salgan fuera del main siendo este el padre. Entonces no sale de este tamaño, pero aun asi crece si el contenedor-listado, sigue agregandole nuevos li uno abajo de otro y este contenedor ya que no tiene scroll sigue y sigue creciendo (es como que se estira el contenedor padre a pesar de tener un tamaño fijo y tambien el contenedor hijo solo que este no tiene un tamaño fijo). Ademas de eso, el sidebar tambien estira junto con el main y el contenedor-listado. Entonces COMO PUEDO EVITAR ESTO, ya me esta sacando canas...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]